# Calculate the diffusion coefficient from a random walk with stay.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, random-walk, numerical-optimization

I am working on a problem involving a random walk inspired by protein motion in biological cells. It is assumed that motion in time is a stochastic process. In this case, the simple 1D random walk evolving in time, $t$.

To avoid considering boundary conditions I establish an infinite domain and solve the following numerically.
$$
\mathrm{RW} = x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^T \Delta x s(r),
$$
here $x_0$ is my initial location and has been simply $x_0 = 0$, $T$ represents the final time and is discredited by $\Delta t$, $s$ is a random function, $r$ is representing what I am calling the *hopping rate*, and $\Delta x$ is my spatial step size.

The random function goes like this

$$
s(r) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & 0 \leq U < r\Delta t, \\  
-1 & r \leq U < 2r\Delta t, \\  
0 & \mathrm{Otherwise}, 
\end{cases}
$$
where $U\sim{\sf U}(0,1)$. So in this case, I have seen this type of RW called an RW with stay. I understand that if I simulate this $N$ times, where $N$ is large, and plot all random walks I should see the equivalent of a 1D diffusion equation. I know also that $0 \leq r \leq 1$ can change the overall variance of the RW process and that this can be evaluated by looking at the mean squared displacement.

Now I know there are similar posts here dealing with random walks and their respective diffusion coefficient.

1. [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336157/derive-diffusion-coefficient-for-heat-equation-from-random-walk-simulation)
2. [Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/wiener-process-and-random-walk)
3. More, etc...

I am having trouble being able to relate this so-called *hopping rate* to the diffusion coefficient at the time ($Dt$) in

$$
\mathbb{P}(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi Dt}}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{Dt}\right),
$$
for the 1D case that is. My actual problem is two or three dimensional. I have considered that $D$ is in length squared over time units and that my domain is in length units making
$$
r\Delta t = \frac{D \Delta t}{2 \Delta x^2}
$$
seem reasonable. I have worked this out and I visually can see a similar spread between the distribution equation and simulating a million RWs, but the count in the RW is much higher than the solution function. I am currently working on just solving the diffusion equation with a forward Euler time explicit scheme, but I am just running into problems relating the $D$ to my $r$ values and $t$ in the distribution matching the right scale of T in the RW.

Any help would be welcomed. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you have is covered as Position Jump Process II in

> Erban, Radek, and S. Jonathan Chapman. "Reactive boundary conditions for stochastic simulations of reaction–diffusion processes." Physical Biology 4.1 (2007): 16.

One important thing, normal distribution approximation of Brownian Motion, i.e.,

$$
P(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi Dt}}\exp(\frac{x^2}{4Dt})
$$

is only valid for no stay cases. If you have a stay probability, depending on how large the stay probability is, you will observe deviations from that formula. The reason is that this formula is derived as [a limiting case of a binomial distribution](https://people.bath.ac.uk/pam28/Paul_Milewski,_Professor_of_Mathematics,_University_of_Bath/Past_Teaching_files/stirling.pdf) where there are only two outcomes at each step using the Stirling approximation.

Back to the question, $D$ for no stay case is defined as

$$
D=\frac{l^2}{2\Delta{t}},
$$
where $l$ is the jump length. As you said, you can use mean squared displacement to calculate $D$ and for your case, it looks like

$$
D=\frac{\Delta{x}^2(1-2r\Delta{t})}{2\Delta{t}}.
$$

PS: There are many other derivations of normal distribution, starting from binomial distribution is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a derivation of the random walk with three different probabilities P-, P0 and P+ in this publication: Random walks Marc R. Roussel Department of Chemistry and Biochemistry University of Lethbridge ([https://people.uleth.ca/~roussel/C4000statmech/random_walk.pdf](https://people.uleth.ca/%7Eroussel/C4000statmech/random_walk.pdf)).

But, in my case, working out the relation:

$ x(t+\Delta t) = x(t)+\Delta x ·\eta(t)$ where $\eta(t) = 1,0,-1$ depending on if you move forward, stay or backward,

I found $D=\frac{(P_{+}+P_{-})-(P_{+}+P_{-})^{2}}{2}·\frac{\Delta x ^2}{\Delta t}$

(Where $\Delta x$ is the step size and $\Delta t$ is the simulation step time).